# How do I enable audit logging for Google Container Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, audit-logging

Running a GKE cluster with 1.8.1 - when I look at `/logs/kube-apiserver-audit.log`, it's completely empty. I've taken actions like creating deployments and deleting pods that have been visible in audit logs for clusters I've provisioned outside of GKE.

Is there a better way to view or access these kinds of events with GKE?

Comment: > when I look at `/logs/kube-apiserver-audit.log`

Where do you look at this file in GKE setup?

Comment: I was running `kubectl proxy`, then viewing those logs from localhost. That meant the full URL was `http://127.0.0.1:8001/logs/kube-apiserver-audit.log`. The full apiserver log at `http://127.0.0.1:8001/logs/kube-apiserver.log` was full of events as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because Container Engine 1.8 release does not enable the audit logging feature yet. From [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes):

> KNOWN ISSUE: Audit Logging, a beta feature in Kubernetes 1.8, is currently not enabled on Container Engine.

It will probably be enabled at some point in the future, I’d keep an eye on the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes).